# Tortoise SVN Build using Visual C++ FAILS

Tags: visual-c++, tortoisesvn, linker-errors

I am trying to build TSVN using Visual Studio and have followed all the steps of the build.txt but I am getting the following errors:

```
*****ERRORS********* Error 50 fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '../../ext/Subversion\release_win32\libsvn_repos.lib' TortoiseProc TortoiseProc

Error 1 fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '../../ext/Subversion\release_win32\libsvn_wc-nonet.lib' SubWCRevCOM SubWCRevCOM
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggest that you don't have all the required libraries. A few variants as to how yo got here:

- you either misstyped the path to the include folder (where the .lib files are) - try searching for the files that are not found and adjust the include paths

  OR
- you have to build the project(s) in a certain order to avoid getting this error messages. Build the projects that output `libsvn_repos.lib` and `libsvn_wc-nonet.lib` first. Check the dependencies for each project and build first the projects that do not have dependencies on the other projects in the sollution

I haven't built TSVN myself so these are just guesses. But why don't you just use the install kit and avoid all this trouble ?

Comment: Thanks John... I am actually customizing the TSVN Client for my organization, only have to remove a few features, like create repository,Export,Import, etc... Hence need to build the source code first and then make a setup of the customized client.

I tried building according to the document but nothing worked. 
Searched the entire project for any program that generated these files but to no avail... :-(
Thanks for you help..truely appreciated...

Comment: @Richa: You should make sure that you have all the libraries that come with SVN and that they are found by the projects that need them: Write in the `Project Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories` the path where these two libraries are found. If you don't have them, get them from the [SVN home page](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.. I have built Subversion but I am unable to find the .lib file anywhere on my system. I could locate libsvn-repos.dll but not the .lib file... What can be done?

Comment: Will it work, if I manually create Subversion .lib files from the subversion .dll files????

Comment: Try to create a new [static library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx) project with the same files included in the dinamic link library project.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is a GUI front-end for Subversion, and it uses Subversion libraries as the back-end. Thus, you must compile Subversion or obtain the compiled binaries for your version of Visual Studio before compiling TortoiseSVN. After that, modify the paths that point to Subversion libraries to reflect your setup.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.. I have built Subversion but I am unable to find the .lib file anywhere on my system. I could locate libsvn-repos.dll but not the .lib file... What can be done?

Thanks in advance for your valuable support !!

Comment: Will it work, if I manually create Subversion .lib files from the subversion .dll files????

Comment: If you built Subversion from the makefiles, make sure you do not run commands (makefile targets) that clean up the build directory such as `make clean`, because this normally deletes all files produced after the configuration, the compilation and the linkage phases. You should be able to extract the .lib from the .dll also, but I recommend building from scratch if you can. Another option would be to load the .dll dynamically.